# Compare rows in a dataframe in spark, to assign value to a column based on comparison of rows

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data will look like below

Journey Table

| SERNR | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | null |
| 456 | null |
| 789 | null |

Segment Table

| SERNR | Sgmnt | FROM-Station | TO-Station |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 01 | A | B |
| 123 | 02 | B | C |
| 123 | 03 | C | B |
| 123 | 04 | B | A |
| 456 | 01 | A | B |
| 456 | 02 | B | C |
| 456 | 03 | C | D |
| 456 | 04 | D | A |
| 789 | 04 | A | B |

I want to join these two data frames/tables and have check on the journey station `FROM` and `TO`  to decide a journey type, i.e if its return journey some type `A` if its mirror return some type `B`, if its a one-way journey some type `C`

type calculation will be as follows

lets say for journey **SERNR** **123**, the journey details are *A->B , B->C, C->B,B->A*, this is a mirror journey, because its *A-B- C* then *C-B- A*.

for **789** its *A->B* so its a normal journey .

for **456** its *A-> B, B->C , C->D , D-A,* in short *A-B-C* then *C-D-A* , this is a return but not a mirror

I really don't know how to do a comparison of rows in Dataframe based on `SERNR` to decide the type by checking `FROM` and `To` station of the same `SERNR`

Really appreciate if I can get a pointer to go ahead and implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the list of `FROM` `TO` journeys into an array column for each `SERNR`, then join the array elements to get a `journey_path` (`A-B-C...`).

When you get the journey path for each journey, you can use `when` expression to determine the `TYPE`:

- If first FROM != last TO then it's `normal`
- else : if the reverse of the journey_path == the journey_path the `mirror` otherwise it's a `return`

Note that you need to use a Window to keep the order of the segment when grouping and collecting the list of `FROM - TO`s.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy("SERNR").orderBy("Sgmnt").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

val result = segment_df.select(
    col("SERNR"),
    array_join(
      collect_list(concat_ws("-", col("FROM"), col("TO"))).over(w),
      "-"
    ).alias("journey_path")
  ).dropDuplicates(Seq("SERNR")).withColumn(
    "TYPE",
    when(
      substring(col("journey_path"), 0, 1) =!= substring(col("journey_path"), -1, 1),
      "normal"
    ).otherwise(
      when(
        reverse(col("journey_path")) === col("journey_path"),
        "mirror"
      ).otherwise("return")
    )
  )
  .drop("journey_path")

result.show
//+-----+------+
//|SERNR|  TYPE|
//+-----+------+
//|  789|normal|
//|  456|return|
//|  123|mirror|
//+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cllect_list of from_ station or to_station by grouping  it with SERNR and order with segment